# Angular 11 get params from URL

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, router

I want to get param from my url. I have route structure as

```
{
    path: 'customers/viewCustomer/:id',component:CommonSingleCustomerPageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], data:{ permission:['Manage-Customer']},
    children: [
      {
        path: 'detail',
        component: ViewCustomerComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],data:{permission: ['Manage-Customer']}
      },
}
```

But when I try to get the :id in ViewCustomerComponent, then I get it as undefined.
I have tried the following ways:

```
    export class ViewCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
            private router: ActivatedRoute,
          ) { }
        
          data: any = '';
          id: any = '';
        
          ngOnInit(): void {
            this.id = this.router.snapshot.params.id
            console.log(this.id)
    }
    }
```

and also ,

```
export class ViewCustomerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private router: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  data: any = '';
  id: any = '';

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
    console.log(this.id)
  }
}
```

But none of these works. Any idea that what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to access path route that is defined in parent. so use parent object to access that value (:id) in your child component ViewCustomerComponent

```
this.router.parent.params
```

or refer this article
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-parent-routing-params